# How to correctly validate a modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I can't seem to get validation to work on my bootstrap modal, I have struggled with several of the examples that I have encountered.

What is the correct way to validate a bootstrap modal?

My HTML:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-control" role="form" id="newModalForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required error" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" placeholder="Enter and action">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(function () {        

    $("#newModalForm").validate({
        rules: {
            pName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            action: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            pName: {
                required: "Please enter some data",
                minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
            },
            action: "Please provide some data"
        }
    });
});
```

Based upon my code nothing appears to happen when I click the save button on modal.  I am utilizing the jquery.validate.js script.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried throwing your validation setup code in the modal's `shown.bs.modal` event?

Comment: Where is '#newPermission' in your html?  The form has a different ID than what you are validating.

Comment: I edited the javascript to correctly reference the form id in the modal.

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You're button needs to be set to `type="submit"` not `type="button"`
2. Your submit button should be inside your `form` tag.

See working example Snippet.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#newModalForm").validate({
    rules: {
      pName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
      },
      action: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      pName: {
        required: "Please enter some data",
        minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
      },
      action: "Please provide some data"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name" require/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action" require>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: example in [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) uses an small script which works fine. You are using `jquery.validate.min.js`, is it because sample in bootstrap website doesn't work on modals?

Answer (score 4):

If you need send data via AJAX from bootstrap modal use following code:

```js
$("#addMyModal form").validate({
  rules: {
    Name: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
   },
    Email: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
   },
    Phone: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 12
   }
  },
  messages: {
    Name: {
     required: "Обязательное поле",
     minlength: "Минимальная длинна Имени 2 символа"
   },
    Email: {
     required: "Обязательное поле",
     minlength: "Минимальная длинна Email 5 символов",
     email: "Пожалуйста введите корректный email адрес."
   },
    Phone: {
     required: "Обязательное поле",
     minlength: "Минимальная длинна Телефона 11 символов"
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: './pay-vip.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    location.replace(location + "pay-vip.php");
                    alert("Send mail")
                }            
            });
          }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name" require/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action" require>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: help me bro @nazar lesyuk, after adding your javascript code my modal form will not pop up can you help me?   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a186b7b50550e99e2ccfbb27849b966

Comment: my modal pop up form is now back... but i want it in AJAX submit Im using cakephp how to make the message inside the pop up form "Successfully save data" then the modal will hide after 3 secs

Answer (score 4):

I had some similar problem. But it turned out that

```
$("#newModalForm").validate({ ... });
```

has to be put outside the

```
$(function () { });
```

This fixed my issue

Comment: `$(function () { });` is the document ready function (all the html tags are rendered). Putting your code that supposed to run after form created before it happen, will definitely cause error.