# Modal Popup Validation not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal popup with Message box. I have write some conditions on form submit but i  want to validate same form with form submit

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="popUpToggle();" id="myModal2" >
<div class="form_fields feedbackfield">
<textarea id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" rows="5" class="form-control contact-input" placeholder="Message *" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form_fields">
<input type="submit" class="contact-submit" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</div>
</form>
```

And Script is

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
            if(localStorage.getItem("modalPopup")){$("#myModal2").modal('hide');}
            else{$('#myModal2').modal('show');}

        }, 5000);

        function popUpToggle(){
            localStorage.setItem("modalPopup", "commit");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Do one thing. First validate the form then setItem to localstorage.

Comment: Yes i did but it not even trigger

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aGJrZ/9/

Comment: $("#myModal2").validate({
 rules: {
   txtMessage: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 8
   },
   
 },
 messages: {
   txtMessage: {
  required: "Please enter some data",
  minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
   },
  
 }
 });
 });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly validate a modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999531/how-to-correctly-validate-a-modal-form)