# jQuery validation not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I have a signup form in an express app. I am using bootstrap for the front-end. I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate the name, email, phone number etc format but it is not working. Here is the HTML layout of the page.

```js
$("#modalForm").validate({
    rules: {
        nameModal: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        emailModal: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        numberModal: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 12
        },
    },
    messages: {
        nameModal: {
            required: "Please enter name",
            minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
        },
        emailModal: {
            required: "Please enter email",
            minlength: "Your data must be at least 5 characters"
        },
        numberModal: {
            required: "Please enter number",
            minlength: "Number should be atleast 9 character"
        },
    }
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 padding: 1%;
}

 
.form-links {
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 4px; 
}
 .form-links a {
  color: #fff;
 }
.formbtn{
 background-color: #5d5d5d; 
 border-color: #d6d6c2;
 font-size: 20px;
}



div.login{
 color: #5d5d5d;
 background-color: #d6d6c2;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 200px; 
 margin-bottom: 8%;
 padding: 4%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.float-right a{
 color: #5d5d5d;
}
.float-right a:hover {
 color: white;
}

/* The signup modal code */
.signup{
 border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.modalcolor{
 color: #5d5d5d;
 background-color: #d6d6c2;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 padding: 2%;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="js/myJs/login.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 login">
            <form  method="POST">
                <h3>Gramleys</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required id="emailLogin" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginPass" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary formbtn">Login</button>
                <button type="button" name="create" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Create</button>
                <br>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <a href="#" class="float-right">Forgot password</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade signup" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modalcolor">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Signup</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <form method="POST" role="form" id="modalForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailModal" placeholder="Email" id="emailModal" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputName">Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameModal"  placeholder="Name" required id="nameModal" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputPassword">Select Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passModal" placeholder="Password" id="passModal" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputNumber">Mobile Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numberModal" min="1" max="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" required id="numberModal">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group d-inline col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label for="InputAge">Age</label>
                                <input style="display: block;"type="number" class="form-control " name="ageModal" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required id="ageModal">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-inline  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label for="InputAge">Weight(kg)</label>
                                <input style="display: block;" type="number" class="form-control " name="weightModal" min="30" max="150" placeholder="Weight" required id="weightModal">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-inline col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                <label for="InputAge">Height(cms)</label>
                                <input style="display: block;" type="number" class="form-control " name="heightModal" min="100" max="200" placeholder="Height" required id="heightModal">
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the jQuery validator not working? I have been trying to work it out a lot but it is not working please help me to sort out this problem. I have looked into other answers on stackoverflow but none seems to resolve this issue. Here is the answer from where i took the above js code [How to correctly validate a modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999531/how-to-correctly-validate-a-modal-form)  Is it because of express or node environment any help would be highly appreciated.
It works here but does not work on my local node server boostrap is installed using npm in the app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPVNh.png) No error message displaying as seen in the image.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: If the user enters the name or emails smaller than the desired length and wrong format the modal gets updated with an error message. Just like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/35001667/7419457

Answer (score 2):

The only problem you are having is that your button falls outside `form` which doesn't trigger the form submit event and hence your form is not validated against it.

You can put that button inside form or you can validate it by this

```
$(".createButton").click(function(e){
  if(!$('#modalForm').valid()){
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```js
$(".createButton").click(function(e) {
  if (!$('#modalForm').valid()) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})

$("#modalForm").validate({
  rules: {
    nameModal: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 8
    },
    emailModal: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    numberModal: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 12
    },
  },
  messages: {
    nameModal: {
      required: "Please enter name",
      minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
    },
    emailModal: {
      required: "Please enter email",
      minlength: "Your data must be at least 5 characters"
    },
    numberModal: {
      required: "Please enter number",
      minlength: "Number should be atleast 9 character"
    },
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 1%;
}

.form-links {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.form-links a {
  color: #fff;
}

.formbtn {
  background-color: #5d5d5d;
  border-color: #d6d6c2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div.login {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  background-color: #d6d6c2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  padding: 4%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.float-right a {
  color: #5d5d5d;
}

.float-right a:hover {
  color: white;
}


/* The signup modal code */

.signup {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.modalcolor {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  background-color: #d6d6c2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script src="js/myJs/login.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 login">
      <form method="POST">
        <h3>Gramleys</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required id="emailLogin" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginPass" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary formbtn">Login</button>
        <button type="button" name="create" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary formbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Create</button>
        <br>
        <div class="float-right">
          <a href="#" class="float-right">Forgot password</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade signup" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content modalcolor">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Signup</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <form method="POST" role="form" id="modalForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailModal" placeholder="Email" id="emailModal" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputName">Full Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameModal" placeholder="Name" required id="nameModal" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputPassword">Select Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passModal" placeholder="Password" id="passModal" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputNumber">Mobile Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numberModal" min="1" max="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" required id="numberModal">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group d-inline col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="InputAge">Age</label>
                <input style="display: block;" type="number" class="form-control " name="ageModal" min="10" max="100" placeholder="Age" required id="ageModal">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group d-inline  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="InputAge">Weight(kg)</label>
                <input style="display: block;" type="number" class="form-control " name="weightModal" min="30" max="150" placeholder="Weight" required id="weightModal">

              </div>
              <div class="form-group d-inline col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="InputAge">Height(cms)</label>
                <input style="display: block;" type="number" class="form-control " name="heightModal" min="100" max="200" placeholder="Height" required id="heightModal">

              </div>
            </div>


          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="submit" class="createButton btn btn-secondary">Create</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but it did not work out. Here i am running the updated code but it doesn't work out https://imgur.com/a/2CZQzxq

Comment: @Rahulroy your button must be outside the form, everything else all right, check my edit in the answer. you have 2 ways to resolve this problem

Comment: or check my snippet it shows working code, and compare it with yours

Comment: Thanks for your time, if you check my snippet then its also working, but when I try it on localhost it doesn't work. I tried both of the changes that you suggested but didn't work.

Comment: @rahul create jsfiddle and give me a link let's see what is the problem here

Comment: Coz of the company privacy policy I cannot share the complete code can you give me your email id I will mail you the complete code.

Comment: @Rahulroy I do not need complete code you can post minimal example to reproduce the issue, this seems very simple to me.

Comment: I have added all the code that this page is dependent upon in the snippet. Don't know why it does not work on my localhost but works over here.

Comment: @Rahulroy inspect it and then debug check where your problem is

Comment: yup trying that, but both browser js console and node console show no error.